# Changing all values at one CSV

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

I want to be able to change all values that meet the condition as one. This moment in time I do one value at the time. It might be more than one value that meet the condition, but it need to be change differently.

Let say value x and value y meet the condition and value x is change to x1 and value y to y1. What I'm trying to do is changing all appearance of value x at one time and all appearance of value y at one time

```
all_rows = []    
for row in all_rows:
        some_num = row[0]
        if strformat.match(some_num):
            continue
    
        change = input(f"\n'{some_num}' doesn't match, change it to: ")
        row[0] = change.strip()
```

Comment: Is this using a dataframe, an array, something else?

Comment: it's taking all rows from a CSV and saving it into a multiline list

Comment: You are prompting for each change. Did you want to prompt once and use that value for all changes?

Comment: There are more than one value that might need to be modified. And what i need is to take value x and change it to the input value on all appearance of value x and one it find value y change it to the input value on all appearance of value y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of changes already given by the user in a dictionary and prompt when a new change is needed.

```
all_rows = []    
changes = {}
for row in all_rows:
        some_num = row[0]
        if strformat.match(some_num):
            continue
        try:
            row[0] = changes[some_num]
        except KeyError:
            change = input(f"\n'{some_num}' doesn't match, change to: ")
            change = change.strip()
            changes[some_num] = change
            row[0] = change
```

Comment: I haven't thought of that. Thanks